# Is there a way I can use chrome driver on heroku while I use python-selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, heroku

I'm trying to use chrome driver for web testing with selenium on heroku.

But I've found that heroku doesn't support chrome driver.
I've consulted with google many times how to use chrome driver on heroku.

I have added buildpack such as https://github.com/jimmynguyc/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git, https://github.com/tstachl/heroku-buildpack-selenium and so on, but I totally failed to use chrome driver.

I would like to know how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already install Chrome?  The Heroku CI site has a [page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-ci-browser-and-user-acceptance-testing-uat) that points out you'll need the buildpack "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome"